# update statement in postgresql for multiple tables join, i want optimized update for below update statement, below statement is taking long time

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

```sql
update tabel1 t1 set column5 = t2.column1, column2 = 0
from table1 t
join table2 t2 on t2.column3 = t.column3
left join table3 t3 on t3.coulmn4 = t.column4
where t3.column5 is null
```

Answer (score 2):

As documented in [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html):

> Do not repeat the target table as a from_item unless you intend a self-join

So, don't repeat the target table in the FROM clause:

```
update table1 t1
   set column5 = t2.column1, 
       column2 = 0
from table2 t2 
  left join table3 t3 on t3.column4 = t2.column4
where t2.column3 = t1.column3 --<< this replaces the original JOIN to t1
  and t3.column5 is null
```

Comment: left join table3 t3 on t3.column4 = t.column4 how is this line possible?? without table 't' reference??

Comment: @PraveenKumarReddy: obviously that's a typo and should be `t2.column4`

Comment: from table2 t2 
  left join table3 t3 on t3.column4 = t2.column4,, here no two columns are matching for table 2 and table 3, So, i cannot able to join these two table, So please provide alternate

Comment: That must be `on t3.column4 = t1.column4`. The query wants to ensure that the updated row has either no match in table3 or only matches with column5 being null. (`NOT EXISTS` would of course be more readable.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: but then there wouldn't be a join between table2 and table3.

Comment: Correct. It's a join to table1 actually. Simplified: The statement shall update t1 rows that have a match in t2, but not in t3. (I've just updated my comment before to say that `NOT EXISTS` would be a better choice in my opinion.) The `FROM` clause not including the updated table, but refering to it, is a tad hard to read/write in PostgreSQL in my opinion.